# Best way for automated ban / throttle of aggressive clients on a Linux / Apache webserver for a period of time?

Tags: web-server, csf, rate-limiting

I notice occasional spikes on my server load and when I check access logs I notice a pattern for some automated forum poster that tries to repeatedly access a comment/reply URL. What would be the best way to throttle /ban these for a few minutes / hours? Can CSF for example do sg like this? I am really looking for a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Awesome, looks like the solution. Care to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iptables could be used to that end.

Blocking parallell connections:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit \
     --connlimit-above 20 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

Blocking floods (block more than 10 connections per minute) :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent \
   --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 10 -j DROP
```